# how to decompose an array into different strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

So i'm passing an array from one activity to another,
when i send the array to the other activity, i want to decompose the array into various strings.
for example :

in first activity :

```
array[] x = [car,ball,mouse,shirt]
```

in second activity :

receive x array[] , then decompose it to :

```
string one = "car"
string two = "ball"
string three = "mouse"
string four = "shirt"
```

so i can use the Toast action for each one of these separately for example.

Here is my actual code :

First Class :

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("key",new String[]{repeat,temp,humidit,activer,food});
Intent i=new Intent(recruiter.this, StructureClass.class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

Second Class :

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
final String[] array= b.getStringArray("key");



Toast.makeText(StructureClass.this, "i want the string to be shown here 
separately for each value! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Change your String into like this 
`new String[]{"repeat","temp","humidit","activer","food"};`

Answer (score 1):

as I understand you you want to split your array to string with separators

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(x);
String.join(", ", list);
```

[image]

Comment: @prozhan it would be good practice in StackOverflow to marke it as Answered

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can be help you.

> Updated
>
> ```
>     final String[] s= b.getStringArray("key");
>     String a = String.join(", ", s);
>     Toast.makeText(StructureClass.this, a , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> ```

Comment: This will add an extra comma in the end.

Comment: @PrashantJha you are the best in testing